# CF10/CF11 web services using Axis2 restarting existing Java objects

Tags: coldfusion, apache-axis

**Original post:**

This is truly bizarre.

I have a web service that has been working since CFMX (that is, since CF6). We recently upgraded to CF10. (Not my choice, I lobbied for CF11.) We have users that required the old WSDL because they generated stubs for their WS client based on old-format WSDL. So I added wsversion="1" to the cfcomponent tag. We get old-style WSDL, but webservices.log says "Using Axis 2 ...". That's unexpected, but not what I'm referring to as truly bizarre. Read on.

The web service is stateless. I hear that session control is possible with CF web services nowadays, but we're not doing that. No Application.cfc, no cfapplication tag. So each cfinvoke is its own, fully self-contained execution, right? Or so I thought. **I'm seeing things in subsequent invocations of the web service that were defined in *previous* invocations of the web service.** It's as if the same memory is being reused.

For example, I use the existence of a variable (with IsDefined) to detect a condition. It occurs in invocation 1. No problem, I fix it. But then the variable still exists in invocation 2!

I define a UDF unconditionally, because it wouldn't have been defined earlier in the invocation. On the next invocation, it blows up complaining that I attempted to define that UDF twice! Same file! That UDF name defined only once in only that one file!

I conditionally define an array and ArrayAppend trace messages into it in one invocation, and I see the same array still exists and still contains those same trace messages in subsequent invocations! (Hard to argue with same timestamps reappearing.)

All of these symptoms persist until we restart CF Server. Not nice. Not nice **at all**.

It's as if we're restarting old, dirty instantiations of the CFM files' classes, rather than doing a new ClassName() to get our own fresh copies unique to subsequent invocations.

Enable trusted cache is No. Save class files is No. You'd think those 2 alone would require a recompilation of .cfm to .java, then .java to .class, then .class to memory (starting over from scratch on every request), wouldn't you?

This never occurred before, but it's occurring consistently under CF10. Did my sysadmin miss something in the CF10 release documentation?

**UPDATE (same day, 5:40 PM EST):**

As you see in the comments and my responses, below, this problem proved to be Axis 2 only. The wsversion="1" that I thought was in the CFC got edited out, probably by some other well-meaning soul trying to solve this same problem.

Because this CF10 behavior was so horrendous, I got surprisingly quick permission to deploy 2 experimental web services. I now have proof, a minimalistic example that Axis 2 has the problem (at least, at our site, with our config):

/experiments/cf10axis1.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Axis 1 Service" wsversion="1">
<cffunction name="IsFooDefined" access="remote" returntype="string" output="No">
    <cfset Variables.Foo = IsDefined("Variables.Foo")>
    <cfreturn Variables.Foo>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

/experiments/cf10axis2.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Axis 2 Service" wsversion="2">
<cffunction name="IsBarDefined" access="remote" returntype="string" output="No">
    <cfset Variables.Bar = IsDefined("Variables.Bar")>
    <cfreturn Variables.Bar>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

/experiments/call_both_cf10_webservices.cfm:

```
<cfinvoke webservice     = "http://((snip))/experiments/cf10axis1.cfc?wsdl"
          method         = "IsFooDefined"
          refreshWSDL    = "No"
          returnvariable = "Variables.Answer1">
</cfinvoke>
<cfinvoke webservice     = "http://((snip))/experiments/cf10axis2.cfc?wsdl"
          method         = "IsBarDefined"
          refreshWSDL    = "No"
          returnvariable = "Variables.Answer2">
</cfinvoke>
<cfoutput>
Variables.Answer1 = #Variables.Answer1#.<br/>
Variables.Answer2 = #Variables.Answer2#.<br/>
</cfoutput>
```

First call returns

```
Variables.Answer1 = NO.
Variables.Answer2 = NO.
```

All subsequent calls return

```
Variables.Answer1 = NO.
Variables.Answer2 = YES.
```

Can't get much more definitive proof than that.

Damn I love how cleanly StackOverflow renders CFML. Really sweet.

**Confirmed:**

This originally happened in CF10 on Sun Sparc Solaris. I just now ran the same minimalistic test (above) in CF11 on a MacBook Pro and got the exact same result. I've taken the question mark off of this post's Title, and I've made it say CF10/CF11. It's no longer in question.

I don't consider it a CF bug. It's Axis2 that's doing this.

This has serious implications as to how people code, but I can't find any mention of it on the web. Just because you didn't do something in an invocation, doesn't mean it's not that way in memory. Abort flags remain set. You can't use cfparams; you have to used cfsets. Every UDF has to be subordinate to cfif not IsDefined(). The mind boggles.

How am I the first person to discover this? CF11 is out. Is *no one* using Axis2 in CF?

If I weren't such a naturally happy guy, I'd be majorly depressed right now. :-)

Comment: We might be able to help if we could see some code.  See this - http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Comment: I'm in a large organization. To create a small, self-contained example, I need to make a request and wait on approvals.

Comment: Status update: I was working off a set of cfincludes called by the web service. Someone else removed my wsversion="1" in the CFC and I just now found out about it. (That's why Axis 2 was showing up in webservice.log.) I put back wsversion="1" and the problem **WENT AWAY**. So it is for-sure an axis2 problem (as also tagged here). Still need it solved, because we have a need for document literal wrapped. But it's no longer the awful emergency it was just an hour ago.

Comment: I suspect you are aware of this workaround to what seems a mighty horrid behaviour, but in case others are not, here it is. Make the webservice CFC file a simple proxy to another CFC. Each method in your webservice proxy then doing something like:

return CreateObject( "cfcWithActualLogic" ).methodThatWasCalled();

Comment: It's not the behavior I consider horrid, but the lack of warning. "Oh, and by the way, if you switch to Axis2, all of your web services are going to become stateful." All of our web services already are proxies for cfincludes. If you're on same machine, you do a cfinclude. If it resides on different machine, you do a cfinvoke. But a fundamental assumption about coding has changed. ("If I haven't changed it yet, it's still in its initial state.") The cfincludes have to be rewritten to be self-initializing (mainframe term). Did you already know this about Axis2? Where did you hear about it?

Comment: _The Variables scope is not the same as the function local scope, which makes variables private within a function. Always define function-local variables using the var keyword of the Local scope name._ - [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dfb.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d94)

Comment: I know, Miguel. This is different. Axis2 web services are now revealed to be stateful.

Comment: Message for dom_watson: At first I balked at your proxy suggestion, because I thought you meant an Axis2 service proxying an Axis1 service. (That wouldn't've worked for me, because I'd lose document literal wrapped capabilities.) But now I think you're saying that an Axis2 service can proxy an Axis2 service and force a new instantiation. I looked thru your blog and couldn't find more info. Would you please tell me more, or at least a URL? How did you hear of the technique? Or did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: See this blog post from Raymond Camden made today - [Unexpected behavior with Axis2 web services in ColdFusion](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/7/10/Unexpected-behavior-with-Axis2-web-services-in-ColdFusion#c492F8C0F-03DC-4BF5-D8D1415E1F836024)  Maybe related findings?  He entered a bug with Adobe if so.

Comment: Miguel, yes. Still unresolved here so maybe we should monitor the bugbase: [link](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3787631)

Comment: Just noticed how to notify previous poster. @dom_watson, please see my Jul 9 at 13:22 comment, 3 above this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dom_watson (Dominic Watson) posted a workable solution, above. I wish I could give him credit for the correct answer, but I can't figure out how to do that. (Yes, I'm a StackOverflow newb. Yes, I apologize.)

At first I wasn't hopeful. After all, files cfincluded by Axis2 web services were affected by the caching too, even though they were compiled to separate Java class files. It seemed totally dreadworthy that CreateObject() would pick up an in-memory copy of the object.

That didn't happen.

/experiments/cf10axis2proxy.cfc (Axis2 web service):

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Axis2Proxy" wsversion="2">
<cffunction name="IsImpDefined" access="remote" returntype="string" output="No">
    <cfset Variables.ImplObject = CreateObject("component", "experiments.cf10axis2impl")>
    <cfreturn Variables.ImplObject.IsImpDefined()>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

/experiments/cf10axis2impl.cfc (note, not even a web service, access is "public"):

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Axis2Implementation">
<cffunction name="IsImpDefined" access="public" returntype="string" output="No">
    <cfset Variables.Imp = IsDefined("Variables.Imp")>
    <cfreturn Variables.Imp>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Added to /experiments/call_both_cf10_webservices.cfm (see above):

```
<cfinvoke webservice     = "http://((snip))/experiments/cf10axis2proxy.cfc?wsdl"
          method         = "IsImpDefined"
          refreshWSDL    = "Yes"
          returnvariable = "Variables.Answer3">
</cfinvoke>
```

Also added Variables.Answer3 to the cfoutput display, of course.

First execution yielded

```
Variables.Answer1 = NO.
Variables.Answer2 = NO.
Variables.Answer3 = NO.
```

and all subsequent executions yielded

```
Variables.Answer1 = NO.
Variables.Answer2 = YES.
Variables.Answer3 = NO.
```

So it's tested and confirmed (under CF11, despite the file names). dom_watson's suggestion makes a cfinvoke of an Axis2 web service behave the way https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfinvoke *says* cfinvoke behaves:

- **Transiently** instantiates a component or web service and invokes a method on it.

(emphasis added).

Thank you, Dominic.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue in Axis 2.

This is a change in behavior in how the Axis 2 web services support was designed.

In Axis 1, for every web service request a new CFC instance is created and the request was handled by this new instance. That is why the variables always gets re initialized for every request.

In Axis 2, the CFC instance is created only for the first time you are accessing the service (First time accessing the WSDL, or first call to the web service). For every subsequent requests the same instance is used. So you are seeing the caching there. A new CFC instance will be created only if service CFC is modified.

Normally if you are deploying an axis2 based aar (using Java), in tomcat, you will see the same behavior. i.e., If your class has state and that state is modified with in the web service function, you will get the modified value in the next request.

This was a design decision we took to improve the performance (To not initialize the instance every time and registering it with Axis 2 framework, but to re use the instance). Do you have a requirement to use different CFC instances for each web service request?

Comment: I see on LinkedIn that you work for Adobe, so I believe you when you say that it was designed that way. Now that I know that it's a feature, not a bug, I suppose I'll have to code around it. Axis 2 will certainly write a new chapter in what constitutes ColdFusion "best practices". Please let your employer know, it would have been nice to have some forewarning in the documentation about this behavior. And yes, I do have a requirement to use different CFC instances. But for now, I'll code around it. Thanks again for the inside scoop.

Comment: More for Paul_Nibin: Thanks again for your earlier reply. I think I see why CF's implementation of Axis 2 is stateful. It allows for the possibility of a series of calls, in the manner of a drill-down, where each call is dependent on the results of earlier calls. But to what extent is there a partition between 2 users accessing the same WS? Is state maintained across all users? If so, I'd imagine that there'd have to be some locking mechanism to keep 2 simultaineous users from overwriting each other's memory. True?